# update table mariadb from bash script

Tags: mysql, bash, mariadb

Trying to write an table update statement in my bash script but gives me a syntax error
mysql  Ver 15.1 Distrib **5.5.68-MariaDB**, for Linux (x86_64) using readline 5.1

```
mysql -u UserName --password=MyPassword -D MyDatabase -e 'UPDATE MyTable SET name = SomeName WHERE number = someNumber ;'
```

> ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 1: You have an error in your SQL syntax;
> check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for
> the right syntax to use near 'SomeName  WHERE number = someNumber' at
> line 1

Comment: Does this work when using mariaDB directly? try put '' around 'SomeName'

Comment: @VladL you spotted it right away! I posted the answer below.

Answer (score 1):

So the answer is: **you must escape "" like so \"** one liner to update mysql db from shell:

```
mysql -u userName --password=yourPassword -D databaseName -e "UPDATE tableName SET columnName = \"${variable}\" WHERE numberColumn = \"${numberVariable}\""
```

Comment: Sorry, I put two single quotes together, so it looks like a double quote. Please use single quotes in MySQL queries.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11321491/when-to-use-single-quotes-double-quotes-and-backticks-in-mysql

Comment: @VladL normally yes, but this is bash script so if you put single quotes over ${variable} it will be treated like a string, my version worked for me. 

reference for single quotes in bash: https://www.howtogeek.com/howto/29980/whats-the-difference-between-single-and-double-quotes-in-the-bash-shell/

Comment: hmmm, the outer double-quotes should be sufficient to allow variable expansion (for variables referenced between the double-quotes) while also allowing for single quotes around the SQL strings, eg, `"UPDATE ..... columnName = '${variable}' WHERE numberColumn = '${numberVariable}'"` .. or does mariadb require double-quotes around literal values?